# How to remove LARAVEL from branding and use own branding in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, configuration, branding

In Laravel 5, how could I remove "Laravel" from the forget password email template, and to use my own branding?

Please kindly advise to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#markdown-mailables

Comment: You can edit any part of the application, just change the files under resources/views you wish to modify. Also change the .env and config defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change only the branding then you can set it in .env file

```
APP_NAME=your_app_name
```

---

But if you want to change more stuff, for example the header or footer then you need to do this:

Run these commands

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

and then in

```
/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/
```

you can edit all the components and customize anything you want.
For example i have edited the sentence All rights reserved. to All test reserved in

```
/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php
```

and this is what i got:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That actually comes from the configuration setting in `app.php`, called `name`. There's also an environment variable called `APP_NAME`.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L15 - Config value

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example#L1 - Environment variable

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the name to your own, you just have to update your variable in .env file:

```
APP_NAME=*the-name-of-application*
```